# Checkboxes Do Not Get Processed Even Without Pagination

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I'm aware that with pagination, if a checkbox is clicked and you move onto another page, that checked checkbox is no longer recognized, so I made my php pull depending on a category chosen by the user, and each row spits out in a w3css w3-third div:

```
while($rowtbl = mysqli_fetch_array($resulttbl)) {

    ?>
<div id="parent">
                <div class="<?php echo $rowtbl['brand']?>">
                    <section class="allitems">
                        <div class="w3-third w3-margin-bottom" id="itemsToFilter" data-type="<?php echo $rowtbl['brand']?>">
                            <ul class="w3-ul w3-border w3-center w3-hover-shadow" >
                                <li class="w3-padding-16 w3-green">Desc:&nbsp;<b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rowtbl['description']) ?></b>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="descriptionid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowtbl['description']; ?>"  /></li>
                                <li class="w3-padding-4">Brand:&nbsp;<b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rowtbl['brand']) ?></b>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="brandid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowtbl['brand']; ?>"  /></li>
                                <li class="w3-padding-4">Category:&nbsp;<b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rowtbl['category']) ?></b>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="categoryid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowtbl['category']; ?>"  /></li>
                                <li class="w3-padding-4">Item#:&nbsp;<b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rowtbl['itemNu']) ?></b>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="itemid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowtbl['itemNu']; ?>"  /></li>
                                <li class="w3-padding-2">Pack Size:&nbsp;<b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($rowtbl['packsz']) ?></b>
                                <input type="hidden"  name="packszid<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $rowtbl['packsz']; ?>"  /></li>
                    <?php if ($rowtbl['bc'] == "Y") { ?>
                    <li class="w3-padding-10">Broken Cs:&nbsp;<b><input type="checkbox" value="checkedup" name="bcase<?php echo $i; ?>"  /></b></li>
                                <?php }
                                 else { ?>
                    <li class="w3-padding-10">Broken Cs:&nbsp;<b><input type="checkbox" value="notcheckedup" name="bcase<?php echo $i; ?>" disabled /></b></li>
                            <?
                            }
                            ?>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox<?php echo $i; ?>" /></li>
                    <input type="hidden" name="roses" id="roses" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="filler<?php echo $i; ?>" id="filler" />

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>

            </div>
<?php $i++; //increment counter variable
} ?>
```

Everything is fine in regards to adding any item(s) to the db, until I get to any div passed 142.  After that, when i click add, the page refreshes as if it was processed, but nothing gets added to the db.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: showing the php that adds items to the db:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitnew'])){
    for ($i=1;$i<=$_POST['roses'];$i++)
{
     if(isset($_POST['checkbox'.$i]))
     {
                        $custnum = $_SESSION['customerNumber'];
                        $category = $_POST['categoryid'.$i];
                        $brand = $_POST['brandid'.$i];
                        $description = $_POST['descriptionid'.$i];
                        $pksz = $_POST['packszid'.$i];
                        $itemnum = $_POST['itemid'.$i];


                        if($_POST['bcase'.$i] == "notcheckedup")
                                    {
                                        $bcc = "n";
                                        $eaa = 0;

                                    } elseif ($_POST['bcase'.$i] == "checkedup" && isset($_POST['bcase'.$i]))
                                        { $bcc = "y";
                                          $eaa = 1;

                                                } else
                                                   {
                                                           $bcc = "y";
                                                           $eaa = 0;
                                                   };

                    $ordNew = "INSERT INTO `abc123` (`CustNo`,`category`, `brand`, `description`, `pksz`, `ea`, `itemNu`, `bc`) values('$custnum', '$category', '$brand', '$description', '$pksz', '$eaa', '$itemnum', '$bcc')";
                        mysqli_query($link, $ordNew);
                        }
                        header("Location: index.php");
}
```

}
?>

Comment: nothing in your code adds anything to a db

Comment: You're going to want to use AJAX, and a session or cookie.

Comment: `$_POST` size and variables is limited in php.ini see: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars and http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Comment: @nogad - sorry i didn't show the php where it adds to the db b/c i did not the issue was there, since it was adding to the db until up to the 142nd div..but i just edited my question and showed the php that adds to the db..

Comment: @fyrye is there any reason i shouldn't increase the max size?  I changed the values in my php.ini to upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M   memory_limit is alreaydy 128M..I think i  read that i have to restart apache server...need to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @PHPglue i'm new to coding all together, and i've seen the ajax suggestions online, but it's hard for me to wrap my head around.  Thank you though

Comment: @RyanVincent in regards to your first answer..if i gave each checkbox a value ( '<? php echo i' since i'm pulling each row with i=0, whileloop, i++), wouldn't that still give me the same number of $_POST size, and thus the issue would still be php cannot handle the size?  As for your second post, are you asking me to do a var_dump to see if Any checboxes are being processed?  If that's the reason, yes, checkboxes up to about 140th checkbox, get processed...ie, are updated in the db when i click submit.  Please let me know if i'm misunderstanding anything on either of your suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I don't process checkboxes by just getting the name of it in `$_POST`. I normally identify them by the value they return. I use the name to group them and link them to some item or property. As long as it works for you then stay with it.

Comment: @niro only to prevent potential denial of service attacks on poorly configured servers. You will need to also increase the `max_input_vars` since they are limited to `1000` so `8*140+1=1221` at least of the snippet submitted. The `post_max_size` *should* be fine, as I doubt it is over `32M`, which would cause the entire submission to be `empty` once that limit is exceeded. Yes you would need to either wait for the Apache cache propagation, restart the service, or use .htaccess to set the variables using `mod_php` and `php_value` which applies to `PHP_INI_ALL` and `PHP_INI_PERDIR` settings.

Comment: @niro  one suggestion is to remove the bulk of the hidden form values that were retrieved from the database and use the item `id` to query the data from the database and insert the variable data values such as the quantity and customer id. `"INSERT INTO abc123 (CustNo,category, brand, description, pksz, ea, itemNu, bc) SELECT $custnum, category, brand, description, pksz, $eaa, itemNu, bcc FROM abc WHERE itemNu = $itemnum LIMIT 1"` This will also prevent client-side alteration and add validation of the item's existence in the database.

Comment: @fyrye Thank you! I did your last suggestion worked for me!!  I want to mark your post as Answered but I see no green check mark option or any option for that matter next to any comments...maybe b/c i'm new here?..

Comment: @niro I didn't post it as an answer, as your issue could be related to multiple issues, so it can't be marked as answered. Just glad to be of help. Keep in mind that it will be a temporary fix, at least until the `max_input_vars` is exceeded again by additional records.